# Authentication Error While Connecting to Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, authentication

Exception while connecting to Mongo DB :

Below is the Stack Trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "code" : 18 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed."}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:899)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:432)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:443)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:293)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:498)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:621)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:657)
    at mongoOperations.mongoOperations.getConnectionMongo(mongoOperations.java:103)
    at mongoOperations.mongoOperations.main(mongoOperations.java:138)
```

Below is the Code Snippet :

```
private static void getConnectionMongo(){

    try{
        String uri = "mongodb://accountUser:password@127.0.0.1/test";
        MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(uri);
        MongoURI mongoURI = new MongoURI(mongoClientURI);
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(mongoURI);
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("accountUser", "password");
        SimpleMongoDbFactory dbFactory =  new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, "test", userCredentials);
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(dbFactory);
        DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("table");
        DBCursor cursor =  collection.find();
        while(cursor.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e){

    }
}
```

Below is the Code snippet from mongo Shell:

> `db.auth('accountUser','password');`
>   1

These are the jar files used :
spring-data-mongodb-1.3.0.RELEASE,
mongo-java-driver-2.13.2

Any advice will be appreciable. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Either pass this URI

```
String uri = "mongodb://accountUser:password@127.0.0.1/test";
```

or pass userCredentials to constructor both can not go together, still can you highlight which line exactly it throws an error

1. `MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(dbFactory);`
2. `DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("table");`
3. `DBCursor cursor =  collection.find();`

Comment: Yeah i changed the code to UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("adminUser", "password");
  Mongo mongo2 = new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017);
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo2, "Yatra", userCredentials);
  DBCollection collection =mongoTemplate.getCollection("url_entries"); DBCursor cursor =  collection.find();
  while(cursor.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(cursor.next());
  }
  }
  catch(UnknownHostException e){   
  }        This is the Line giving Error: DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("url_entries");

Comment: your mongo db name is Yatra that have collection url_entries , if so what is output of use Yatra and show collections command on mongo console . if all looks good here then i think port is not 27017 . please can you recheck....sorry if that irritates you